# listview.builder not showing items on screen

Tags: flutter, listview, mobile

So I have been trying to figure out how to get the listview.builder() to work within Flutter to no avail. Here, I have a list of dictionaries with 3 keys in each. If you look in the Homepage() widget I am returning a Todo() widget, which is a widget Itaking 3 arguments, each being for a text. For some reason the widget isn't showing up on my app, I have tried to use the dictionary values for the arguments on the Todo widget since it seemed like the sensible thing to do, but unfortunately it isn't working. I am hoping some more experienced Flutter devs can help me out, thanks!

Code:

```
  List todoData = [
{
  'todo': 'Pick up milk',
  'time': 'Time: 10:00AM',
  'urgency': 'Urgency: Important',
},
{
  'todo': 'Pick up milk',
  'time': 'Time: 10:00AM',
  'urgency': 'Urgency: Important',
},
{
  'todo': 'Pick up milk',
  'time': 'Time: 10:00AM',
  'urgency': 'Urgency: Important',
},
{
  'todo': 'Pick up milk',
  'time': 'Time: 10:00AM',
  'urgency': 'Urgency: Important',
},
{
  'todo': 'Pick up milk',
  'time': 'Time: 10:00AM',
  'urgency': 'Urgency: Important',
},


 ];

  Widget HomePage() {
    var index = 0;
    return Center(
      child: ListView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
        children: <Widget>[
          ListView.builder(
            itemCount: todoData.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, index) {
              return Todo(
                  '${todoData[index]['todo']}',
                  '${todoData[index]['time']}',
                  '${todoData[index]['urgency']}',
              );
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

Widget Todo(String titletext, String time, String urgency) {
  return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
      child: Container(
          height: 150,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.blue, borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30)),
          child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
              child: Stack(
                children: <Widget>[
                  TitleText("Pick up Milk"),
                  Positioned(top: 40, child: BodyText("Time: 10:00AM")),
                  Positioned(top: 70, child: BodyText("Urgency: Important")),
                ],
              ))));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to the following.
Remove Center and ListView. Just use ListView.builder.
if You are using ListView.builder inside of a Column then wrap ListView.builder with Expanded widget.

```
 Widget HomePage() {
    return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: todoData.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, index) {
            final item = todoData[index]
              return Todo(
                  "${item['todo']}",
                  "${item['time']}",
                  "${item['urgency']}",
              );
            },
          );
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I used your comment and the other comment to try to come to a solution, but it still isn't showing up. I wrapped my listview.builder in an expanded since it's inside of a column now, but it doesn't seem to show up. Since I can't comment all the code here, it's pretty much your code copy pasted instead of the "Widget" shown on the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use both ListView like that as both are taking fullscreen, in your condition above Listview takes all the screen but for Listview.Builder doesn't have any space to render.

Your code hierarchy should be

```
 Column(children: [
      Expanded(
        child: ListView.builder(shrinkWrap: true,itemBuilder: (ctx, index) {
          return Widget();
        }),
      )
    ]);
```

Comment: Thanks. I ended up putting the code within your hierarchy, which is pretty much the other answer's code copy pasted instead of the Widget() on your answer. Unfortunately it still isn't showing up, but it did show up when it wasn't in a column. Any idea on what's going on?